# how to remove noindex nofollow code that is only showing on Googlebot Smartphone

Tags: noindex, opencart

A website running OpenCart v3 has had "noindex, no follow" added to the code somewhere so that it only shows when viewed by Googlebot Smartphone. I debugged via Dev Tools and found the meta tag added:  when viewed by that device.
The resut is that google has stopped indexing all the site pages!
When I disabled javascript in Dev Tools this code disappeared. But I don't know where in all the OC files to find this code/javascript? Can anyone shed some light on this issue please?!!

Comment: You are asserting an assumption.  Have you tried another phone or desktop? Ask a friend to look at it.

Comment: The issue was explained by Google when I contacted them. They stated that their Googlebot Smartphone, which they use to index sites, read the whole site as noindex, nofollow and explained how to test/show this in Dev Tools. They could not explain how to resolve this. So testing on other devices is not relevant as this is an issue specific to indexing rather than displaying on other devices.